# Why my recent changes in infopath form does not show in the browser?

Tags: infopath, forms-services

I made some changes in my browser enabled, full trust infopath form in visual studio 2008. I successfully published it as xsn file. Then I use central administration tool to add this form again.

I can show my recent changes in InfoPath Designer tool.

But, I can not see these in browser.(I use MOSS 2007) I think Central Administration still serve old form. Because, I saw modifications in infopath designer tool.

Is it possible? Any ideas?

PS: I deactivated form than remove it and after adding it, I activated form again.

Thanks,
Yigit

Comment: Hi @yigit, did you end up solving this? What was the outcome?

Comment: Hi @Russell, it was my mistake. My form had 3 views and I was make changes in first view and look in second view. I wrote this situation below.

Comment: Glad to hear @yigit, it appears Gennady helped you find a resolution, if so you should mark his answer as accepted. This will encourage people to answer questions in the future. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see changes in browser based form from published form template you should have published the template (XSN) upon changing it  which I could not find in your narration

**Update:**
I would have checked that:

- the name (and location) is the same as it is shown in **"Template URL:"** of library form Advanced Settings?
- and you can open it as the same changed template in Infopath Designer there by clicking "Edit Template" link
- trying to publish it under another name (**"Template URL:"** of library form Advanced Settings) reaolves the issue

Comment: After making changes in Visul Studio, I published it again. And add it from Central Administration tool.

Comment: Can you check that the name (and location) is the same as it is shown in "Template URL:"  library form Advanced Settings? and you can open it (the same changed template) in Infopath Designer there by clicking "Edit Template" link?

Comment: Sorry for mess. My form template has 3 views. I modified the code for first view and look second view :( thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

If you have a full-trust form and need to change any promoted columns etc, you will need to de-activate and re-activate the site collection feature on the site collections the form has been deployed to.

You can do this either through Manage Form Templates in central administration, or through site settings->site collection features.